# Netsuite suitecloud in eclipse defaulting to 2.0 api

Tags: netsuite

I just installed the recent 2017.1 suitecloud update for eclipse and now my suitescript is defaulting to 2.0. I need to switch it to 1.0.
[Pic of eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB4Aj.png)

Comment: NetSuite is pushing transition to 2.0 very hard. I was told by a member of the SuiteScript team that they will be disallowing creation of new 1.0 Scripts "in the next few releases, though not within 1 year".

Comment: Some people said the same thing last year at SuiteWorld, some did not.  I've been told by one of the VP's of Engineering that they have no plans on removing 1.0, as it would severely impact many large customers, and cause them to lose business.  Aside from that, as nice as 2.0 is compared to 1.0, it still has a ton of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've created a SuiteScript 2.0 project and you're trying to create a SuiteScript 1.0 file inside it.  Try creating a new NetSuite Project and make sure you select version 1.0, then create a file inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Krypton is 100% correct.  Create a new project and set it to use 1.0.  Or just change the preset code to 1.0 format.  The SuiteScript version is just there to prefill the file will the standard items/formatting that would be in each file.